# Expected value of random variable $Y$

Tags: probability

> If the probability distribution of random variable $Y$ in a given table.What is the expected value of $Y$

> $y_{i}\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;-5\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 1\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 4 $

> $p_{i}\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;0.4\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 0.5\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 0.1 $

What i try

$$E(Y)=\sum y_{i}p_{i}=(-5)\times (0.4)+(1)\times(0.5)+(4)\times(0.1)=-2+0.5+0.4=-1.1 $$

Can anyone please tell me is i am right.

I have seems that it is wrong because expected value os not negative.

Help me please , Thanks

Comment: Expected value can be negative.  The probabilities cannot be.

Comment: Thanks RJM. is,my solution is right

Comment: You're welcome. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Expected value can be either positive or negative. Think of it as a real-world application: Say you have a $50\%$ chance of winning $\$10$ and a $50\%$ chance of losing $\$20$. The expected value of money you *win* is a negative value, $\$-5$. However, the *probability* that something occurs is always positive (or 0).

Therefore, you are correct.